# Quiero imprimir un array json con la función keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, mysqli

Esta es la tabla donde quiero imprimir el resultado y lo hace, pero sólo me muestra un sólo registro

```
<table id="listadoVehiculos" class="table table-sm">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Patente del vehículo</th>
        <th>Marca</th>
        <th>Modelo</th>
        <th>Año</th>
        <th>Fecha de registro</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="rowsVehiculos">
    
    <tr>
        <td id="patenteVehiculo">  </td>
        <td id="marcaVehiculo">  </td>
        <td id="modeloVehiculo">  </td>
        <td id="anioVehiculo">  </td>
        <td id="fechaRegistro">  </td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
                
            </div>
            
        </td>
    </tr>      
</tbody>
</table>
```

En mi archivo main.js tengo la función keyup que la tengo de la siguiente manera :

```
if( $('#txtSearch').length )
{
    $('#txtSearch').keyup(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        const dataSearch = $('#txtSearch').val();
        const action = 'searchVehiculoKey';
        var dataVehiculo = '';

        $.ajax({
            url: './app/ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            data: {
                action:action,
                dataSearch:dataSearch
            },
            success:function(response)
            {
                if( response == "notData")
                {
                    dataVehiculo = "No se encontraron registros";
                }
                else
                {
                    const info = JSON.parse(response);
                    console.log(info);
                    
                    $.each(info, function( index, value ) {
                        dataVehiculo = `<tr>
                                            <td id="patenteVehiculo"> ${info.patente} </td>
                                            <td id="marcaVehiculo"> ${info.marca} </td>
                                            <td id="modeloVehiculo"> ${info.modelo} </td>
                                            <td id="anioVehiculo"> ${info.anio_vehiculo} </td>
                                            <td id="fechaRegistro"> ${info.fecha_registro} </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
                                                    <a href="?controlador=vehiculos&accion=editar&patente=${info.patente}" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a>
                                                    <a href="?controlador=vehiculos&accion=borrar&patente=${info.patente}" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>`
                                
                    });
                }
                $('#rowsVehiculos').html(dataVehiculo);
            },
            error:function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Y en mi archivo ajax.php es donde ejecuto el query que creo que es donde tengo el problema, creo que es dentro del if pero no sé cómo resolverlo, he hecho algo parecido antes pero con PDO

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'searchVehiculoKey')
{   //Buscar por tecla presionada
    $searchData = $_POST['dataSearch'];
    trim($searchData);
    $query = " SELECT * FROM vehiculos WHERE 
                patente LIKE '%$searchData%' OR 
                marca LIKE '%$searchData%' OR 
                modelo LIKE '%$searchData%' OR
                anio_vehiculo LIKE '%$searchData%' OR
                fecha_registro LIKE '%$searchData%' ";
    $query_select = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
    if( !empty($query_select) AND mysqli_num_rows($query_select) > 0 )
    {
        $arrVehiculo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_select);
        echo json_encode($arrVehiculo,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'notData';
    }
    exit;
```

El código me funciona, sólo que no me muestra todos los resultados que deberían coincidir con el LIKE '%$searchData%', alguien me podría ayudar por favor, es para mi proyecto de titulación. De ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: En cada iteración estás sobrescribiendo la variable `dataVehiculo = `<tr>...` y debes concatenar cambiando `=` por `+=`

Comment: Estimado @Triby gracias por tu respuesta, al momento de hacerlo me imprime el primer registro 5 veces, y a medida que escribo una patente en particular me muestra 5 veces esa patente.

Comment: La respuesta de @CristianCamilo es acertada, primero limpia el contenido de la tabla y con eso se soluciona. Si es correcto, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada, para que otros usuarios con problemas similares sepan que eso puede servirles.

Answer (score 0):

Debes concatenar la variable dataVehiculo no reemplazarla en cada recorrido(**dataVehiculo =+** ), y debes vacia el tbody antes para no acumular los datos
**$("#rowsVehiculos").empty();**

```
if( $('#txtSearch').length )
{
    $('#txtSearch').keyup(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        const dataSearch = $('#txtSearch').val();
        const action = 'searchVehiculoKey';
        var dataVehiculo = '';
       
        $.ajax({
            url: './app/ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            data: {
                action:action,
                dataSearch:dataSearch
            },
            success:function(response)
            {
               $("#rowsVehiculos").empty();
                if( response == "notData")
                {
                    dataVehiculo = "No se encontraron registros";
                }
                else
                {
                    const info = JSON.parse(response);
                    console.log(info);
                    
                    $.each(info, function( index, value ) {
                        dataVehiculo =+ `<tr>
                                            <td id="patenteVehiculo"> ${info.patente} </td>
                                            <td id="marcaVehiculo"> ${info.marca} </td>
                                            <td id="modeloVehiculo"> ${info.modelo} </td>
                                            <td id="anioVehiculo"> ${info.anio_vehiculo} </td>
                                            <td id="fechaRegistro"> ${info.fecha_registro} </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
                                                    <a href="?controlador=vehiculos&accion=editar&patente=${info.patente}" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a>
                                                    <a href="?controlador=vehiculos&accion=borrar&patente=${info.patente}" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>`
                                
                    });
                }
                $('#rowsVehiculos').html(dataVehiculo);
            },
            error:function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Cristian, pero me sigue mostrando los mismos 5 datos que mencioné anteriormente, yo creo que el dilema está en la consulta sql :
 if( !empty($query_select) AND mysqli_num_rows($query_select) > 0 )
        {
            $arrVehiculo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_select);
            echo json_encode($arrVehiculo,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }

Comment: Después de la consulta sql mejor dicho, porque de la manera en que lo tengo debe estar capturando el primer valor que encuentra

Comment: LO primero que debe estar funcionando son tus datos, o sino la pregunta pierde el sentido

Answer (score 0):

Lo terminé realizando de la siguiente manera:

```
<table id="listadoVehiculos" class="table table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Patente del vehículo</th>
                <th>Marca</th>
                <th>Modelo</th>
                <th>Año</th>
                <th>Fecha de registro</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody id="rowsVehiculos">
        <?php
            $htmlTable = "";
            foreach( $vehiculos as $vehiculo ) {
                        $htmlTable .= '<tr>
                                            <td id="patenteVehiculo">'.$vehiculo->patente.'</td>
                                            <td id="marcaVehiculo">'.$vehiculo->marca.'</td>
                                            <td id="modeloVehiculo">'.$vehiculo->modelo.'</td>
                                            <td id="anioVehiculo">'.$vehiculo->anio.'</td>
                                            <td id="fechaRegistro">'.$vehiculo->fecharegistro.'</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
                                                    <a href="?controlador=vehiculos&accion=editar&patente='.$vehiculo->patente.'" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                                                    <a href="?controlador=vehiculos&accion=borrar&patente='.$vehiculo->patente.'" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr> '; 
                    }
                    echo $htmlTable;
            ?> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Archivo main.js :

```
if( $('#txtSearch').length )
{
    $('#txtSearch').keyup(function()
    {
        const dataSearch = $('#txtSearch').val();
        const action = 'searchVehiculoKey';
        var dataVehiculo = '';

        $.ajax({
            url: './app/ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            data: {
                action:action,
                dataSearch:dataSearch
            },
            success:function(response)
            {
                if( response == "notData")
                {
                    dataVehiculo = "No se encontraron registros";
                }
                else
                {
                    var info = JSON.parse(response);
                    dataVehiculo = info;
                }
                $('#rowsVehiculos').html(dataVehiculo);
            },
            error:function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    })

}
```

Archivo ajax.php

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'searchVehiculoKey')
{   //Buscar por tecla presionada
    $searchData = $_POST['dataSearch'];
    trim($searchData);
    $query = " SELECT * FROM vehiculos WHERE 
                patente LIKE '%$searchData%' OR 
                marca LIKE '%$searchData%' OR 
                modelo LIKE '%$searchData%' OR
                anio_vehiculo LIKE '%$searchData%' OR
                fecha_registro LIKE '%$searchData%' ";
    $query_select = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
    if( !empty($query_select) AND mysqli_num_rows($query_select) > 0 )
    {
        $htmlTable = '';
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_select) ) {
            $htmlTable .= '<tr>
                                <td id="patenteVehiculo">'.$row['patente'].'</td>
                                <td id="marcaVehiculo">'.$row['marca'].'</td>
                                <td id="modeloVehiculo">'.$row['modelo'].'</td>
                                <td id="anioVehiculo">'.$row['anio_vehiculo'].'</td>
                                <td id="fechaRegistro">'.$row['fecha_registro'].'</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
                                        <a href="?controlador=vehiculos&accion=editar&patente='.$row['patente'].'" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                                        <a href="?controlador=vehiculos&accion=borrar&patente='.$row['patente'].'" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr> '; 
        }
        //echo $htmlTable;
        echo json_encode($htmlTable,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'notData';
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).